# OOP design: Which is parent, admin or user?

Tags: class, oop, inheritance

I have a noobies question about OOP design.

Let's say we have 2 classes: **Admin** with the right to consult, edit and delete; **User** with only consultation right.

How would you design inheritance between these two classes?

Will **Admin** inherits **User** because it is extending further User's functionalities by adding Edition and Deletion right. Or User is inheriting **Admin** with more limitations on the right?

In terms of generalisation, do we say Admin is more 'general' than User and should be superclass. This is what someone senior in my company told me. But from some other designs I was seeing the opposite.
e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567768/Object-Oriented-Design-Principles

Could you clarify which design is correct and perhaps what dis he mean by more 'general'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither idea is appropriate. User's can become Admins, and admins can become Users. Inheritance precludes that ability.

The only reusable bit is the consultation part. Put that isn a separate class that both Admin and User uses.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? How can Admins become Users ? Animals can become Dog but Dogs cannot become Animals. My thought for checking is: Dogs are Animals but not all Animals are Dogs. Rectangles are Quadrilaterals but not vice-versa. In a similar manner, Admins are Users but not all Users are Admins.

Comment: Is it impossible for someone to loose admin privileges in the system you are designing? That would be strange.

Comment: I suppose it is possible. Do you suggest the base classes should be role classes (3 classes Consult, Edit, Delete) for both Admins and Users to use?

Comment: Either that, or two role classes "Editor" (can edit and delete) and "Viewer" (can consult). Editor can inherit from Viewer, but User wouldn't inherit from either. Instead User would have_a Role. your idea would be more flexible but might be more work than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what behaviors your classes had; I could easily see these classes not having any common ancestor.  Take a look at the IPrincipal interface in the .Net framework; it keeps track of the roles which the user has, regardless of whether its and admin or not.